# Is there a canonical cross entropy from the confusion matrix?

Tags: loss-function, cross-entropy

In
Wu, MT. *Confusion matrix and minimum cross-entropy metrics based motion recognition system in the classroom*. Sci Rep 12, 3095 (2022). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-022-07137-z
the author uses a peculiar "cross-entropy formula",

$$
L=-\sum_i (TPR_i + FPR_i) + \log (PPV_i + NPV_i)
$$

where

- TPR is the sensitivity. $TP/(TP+FN)$
- FPR is a False Positive Rate, $FP/(FP+TN)$
- PPV is Positive Predictive Value, $TP/(TP+FP)$
- NPV is Negative Predictive Value, $TN/(FN+TN)$

Can you explain how this idea is related to usual cross-entropy? It seems that its main usage is to optimise for the cut point that defines a positive value.